# Why does my iPhone select a random song when I connect my headphones?

Tags: iphone, music, ios, music.app

Like many other people, I listen to music on my iPhone (6S, iOS 10.0.2) on my way to work. Since the update to iOS 10, I have noticed the following annoying behavior:

When I plug my headphones into my phone, the "Music" app selects a random song from my collection and wants to play that. It doesn't start playing it, but shows the song in the lock screen, waiting for me to press the Play button. I find this really annoying because I would expect to still be at the song that I was listening to last.

Is there a way to change this behavior to my expected behavior (the song I last listened to is selected when I insert my headphones)? From what I remember, that was the default behavior in iOS 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was introduced in **iOS 10**, and the same thing happens when you ask **Siri** to “play music,” or even if you pull up the **Control Center**’s playback controls.

If you *Pause*, then *Resume* only a short while later, the app remembers where you were. But leave it be for an hour or two, and it will forget. At that point it will try to shuffle your entire library when you start music playback.

If you open the **Music** app, it will suddenly remember which song or playlist you were playing last, and you can *Play* from there.

Until Apple fixes it, I’m afraid that’s the only workaround.

Edit: I haven’t encountered this issue since iOS 10.1.1.

Comment: I don't really see how this would be a bug. I would expect the Music app to have to be open for it to play anything at all. It's a pretty big assumption that the mere act of plugging in headphones means I want to listen to music.

Comment: The bug is in that the app doesn’t resume playing what you were playing last (no matter how you ask it to play), and instead plays a random song unless you reopen the app first. Bringing up the music controls when you plug in headphones is part of Predictive, added in iOS 9 and isn’t what @nwinkler is complaining about.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I like the predictive thing, the phone remembers that I listen to music on my way to work when I plug in my headphones in the morning and in the evening. It just shouldn't select a random song, that's taking it a bit too far...